# Correct email data for Google Group API media upload

Tags: gmail-api, google-groups-api

I am trying to use the Google Groups Migration API to add an entry to a Google Group.  According to the documentation I use this url:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/groups/v1/groups/groupId/archive?uploadType=media
```

I am supplying the auth token correctly I think (got past http 401 error).  Now I am getting http 500, internal server error.  My http headers are:

```
Content-Length: 291
Content-Type: message/rfc822
```

The data that follows is as plain a rfc822 type message as I can make:

```
From: "John Doe" <missing_email@domain.com>
To: "Jane Doe" <missing_email@domain.com>
Subject: forward test
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Fri, 19 Feb 2016 08:03:00 -0800
Content-Type: message/rfc822

This is the first line of the forward test.
```

I have some other code that creates messages in Gmail folders, that works fine.  For that, I do "uploadType=multipart", and create my data in json format.  I've tried doing that as well for Groups but no luck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The `Content-Type` of the request is `message/rfc822` as you say, but the actual plain text part of your message is not:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
To: receiver@gmail.com
From: sender@gmail.com
Subject: Subject Text

The actual message text goes here
```

Comment: I think what I'm doing is correct.  I am supplying a chunk of data that is an "message/rfc822".  That in turn has multiple message parts, which can be text, html, etc.  See this Google doc: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#simple.  What should I be putting in place of "Email Message data"?  Anyway, I tried changing the first content-type to message/rfc822 and it still fails.  The json response is "backend error".  Is there a better example I can follow?

Comment: @JeffMcKay I see. I don't know, to be honest. The `Email Message data` could look like the example above, and the rest should be like the example you linked.

Comment: @Tholle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863352/storing-gmail-body-in-mysql-error